# How to activate function reference in WebStorm/PHPStorm?

Tags: php, editor, phpstorm, webstorm

Is there function reference integrated in PHPStorm/WebStorm ?

I mean like when i point my cursor on some php function , then I press e.g. F1 and it will show me function details (parameters, usage...) on separate page.

Is this integrated in phpstorm/webstorm ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally figured it out on my imac. Its CTRL + J on MAC

Comment: Why the downvotes? This worked for me on a Mac with PhpStorm 2.1

Comment: Command+J worked for me. Thanks for sending me in the right direction!

Answer (score 24):

Press Ctrl+Q on any reference to see a doc popup
Press Shift-F1 on any reference to open external link (the one lised in quick doc)

Answer (score 6):

You can also hold down Ctrl and hover over for a quick definition and furthermore click (by default) on the function name to jump to the function definition itself.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers there is Ctrl+Shift+I which pops up a modal with the actual function definition. Further, if you then release Shift+I while keeping Ctrl pressed the call to the function will turn into a link when you mouse over it and clicking it takes you to the source full of the function definition.

Source: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/viewing-definition.html#

Answer (score 0):

select the function, then press **fn + F1**  on MAC, press **CTRL + q** on Windows